# Putting data in different columns in database table

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Is it possible to put data in different columns in the database table but using the same variable used? For example, for column1 is # of hours worked for day1, while column2 is # of hours worked for day2, etc. [image: Here's my database screenshot]

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, add a column for DateTime which stores the dates, then a single column for # of hours worked on that day. Or, a start and end date. This is going against normalization and would grow beyond a table's maximum number of columns (eventually). I didn't DV you BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to normalize the database instead of having all the columns in one table.
You can have one table for all the user information (idnum, first_name,last_name,address) and another table for storing the working hours (idnum, date, timein, timeout). 
Use time columns as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your tables by separating concerns. In your case create three tables namely; users, address, and hours. Specify Primary Keys (PK) in each tables. Use a Foreign Key in your users table to relate to two child tables; address and time_card. Primary keys are idnum, addr_id, and time_id. The last two ids are also foreign keys in the users table. Example table schema and data shown below. Hope this helps.

### users

idnum | first_name | last_name | age  | addr_id | time_id

### 123   | james      | cord      | 32   | 22      |  856

### address

addr_id |  street1        | street2 | city     | state | zip

### 856     | 6830 Woodley Av | Apt 26  | Van Nuys | CA    | 91405

### time_card

time_id | time_in | time_out | date       | day_of_week

### 22      | 8:00 AM | 5:00 PM  | 08/16/2017 | 3